# How to enter two or more places simultaneously in "where" field using google calendar of events?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to enter two or more places in where field of google calendar corresponding to a one day event. How would I do that? Please help. Take a look with the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Google Calendar currently does not support multiple locations in one event. See a [similiar question in the Calendar Product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/calendar/multiple$20locations%7Csort:relevance/calendar/PTJL9E04Aok).

The best you can do now is to create multiple events for the same time and assign a different location to each.

Answer (score 3):

I have successfully managed to add multiple locations in the where field, however it seems to be restricted to only 2 locations.

In the **"Where"** box type:

**FROM "address A" TO "address B"**

Save the event, then click the "map" link that has been generated - it should take you straight to the planned route in Google Maps - not so straightforward on Android though.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 1):

Why not create the trip in google maps, then share it. Find the option for short address. Once you copy the hyperlink, you can paste it into the Where box. You won't be able to tell where you are going by looking in the box, but you can copy the hyperlink and plug it into your cell phone.

Answer (score 1):

What about a combo of Chuck's suggestion and the usual?
Make a map, short URL, but paste it in the "Description" so you can access it. Then in the "Where" box, enter the main place you will be or the name of a place that will clue you in quickly to where you'll be.